# How to Get around null received from a bound form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a **parent form** with a **button**. The button's event is VBA code, that calls a **function**. The function needs to receive some fields from the child form.

**button event:**

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
    Call myFunction(childForm!contactId, childForm!companyId, _
    childForm!lastName, childForm!firstName, childForm!email) 
End Sub
```

The problem is, that sometime some or all of the fields are null, and then I get an error message.

**myFunction:**

```
Public Sub myFunction(ByVal contactId As Integer, ByVal companyId As Integer, _ 
ByVal lastName As String, ByVal firstName As String, ByVal email As String)
```

Is there a way to take care of this aside from writing a long piece of code with conditions and variables?

```
if isnull(childForm!contactId) then
    strContactId = ""
End If
'...etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Nz Function`:

```
    Private Sub btn_Click()
        Call myFunction(Nz(childForm!contactId,0), Nz(childForm!companyId,0), _
        Nz(childForm!lastName,""), Nz(childForm!firstName,""), Nz(childForm!mail,"")) 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh, beat me to it